# Error : Index was outside of the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, loops

When I run this code:

```
Console.Write("How many numbers do you wish to enter? ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number [{0}]: ", i + 1);
        arrayOfNumbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    int minNumber = arrayOfNumbers[0];
    int maxNumber = arrayOfNumbers[0];
    int sumOfNumbers = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arrayOfNumbers[n] < minNumber)
        {
            minNumber = arrayOfNumbers[n];
        }
        else if (arrayOfNumbers[n] > maxNumber)
        {
            maxNumber = arrayOfNumbers[n];
        }

        sumOfNumbers += arrayOfNumbers[n];
    }

    double sumDouble = (double)sumOfNumbers;
    double average = sumDouble / n;

    Console.Write("The min number is : {0}", minNumber);
    Console.Write("The max number is : {0}", maxNumber);
    Console.Write("The sum of the numbers is : {0}", sumOfNumbers);
    Console.Write("The average sum of the numbers is : {0:f2}", average);
```

It gives me an error : Index was outside of the bounds of the array.

The error is at line 28.

I have a task to find min and max number + sum and average of 'n' numbers.

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: That code doesn't produce that problem for me, by the way.

Comment: Same here. Seems to be doing what it was meant to do.

Comment: I tried its working here!

Comment: I have a task to find min, max, sum and average of 'n' numbers. 

Here is the full code : http://pastebin.com/Vnsa0VMJ

Comment: @ДениславАнгелов edit your question instead of throwing some code dump at us. Also, tell us what line exactly is giving you the exception.

Comment: If you need average, min and max there are other ways too

Comment: I can see the error from your link but its not part of your question. Can you  update your question and specify where it is failing?

Comment: Please edit in the code, not the link.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb. I am new here.

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, that's obvious, but I want to make it my way and I'am not sure that the error comes from the method that I am using for finding max and sum.

Comment: oops i removed i guess you did not notice edited part thats why you said No. @PatrickHofman i guess something is being compared which is out of bound..try arrayOfNumbers[n - 1] because array starts filling from 0 which you missed to count!

Comment: @Neel I found it, THANK YOU!

Comment: replace arrayOfNumbers[n]  with arrayOfNumbers[n - 1] everywhere to remove current error. And its just a work around i cant say you wrote the best code @ДениславАнгелов

Comment: @Neel I guess ..  :( It removes the error but the program is not working correctly at all :(

Comment: try to search in internet you will find plenty of examples for your need and learn from it @ДениславАнгелов

Comment: Actually the problem was that arrayOfNumbers[n] needs ot be arrayOfNumbers[i], because its in the loop and I didn't pay attention, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for, you must replace the variable 'n' by 'i'.

Like this:

```
(...)

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arrayOfNumbers[i] < minNumber)
    {
        minNumber = arrayOfNumbers[i];
    }
    else if (arrayOfNumbers[i] > maxNumber)
    {
        maxNumber = arrayOfNumbers[i];
    }

    sumOfNumbers += arrayOfNumbers[i];
}

(...)
```